# Objective-C XML: How to get the value between two tags?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

I'm trying to figure out how to get the value between two tags of an XML text that is being parsed in objective c.

For example, if you have:

```
<tag>thetext</tag>
```

I want to be able to get `thetext`

This seems impossible with the NSXMLParser class or its delegate.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the delegate method :

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser foundCharacters:(NSString*)string
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use TBXML. As long as the tags are known, it's really easy to parse the xml. ;-)